# Работа ZeroMQ в php7

Tags: php, ratchet

Не врубается расширение в WAMP(php7) впрочем сказал отдельно php7 (64 TS) версия. 
Ошибка Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/123/ext/php_zmq.dll' - ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.
 in Unknown on line 0

Поискав - нашел, что расширение не подходит для php7, но https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows 
- Introduces PHP7 support.

На php 5.6 завелось как часы (требуется именно PHP7)

Comment: при чем тут zeromq, если у вас проблемы с mysql?

Comment: не тот варнинг вставил заменил